# How-to use a Regform template, adding field and record data to text file

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need to make a registering user form who once submitted record the information on a server in a text file line per line. (One line per user who fill the form) like:

[SOLVED] Line 1: First Name, LastName, Email, Address, Password
[SOLVED] Line 2: ----------------------------------------------

I really wanted to use this free template (https://colorlib.com/download/2009/) with adding :

[SOLVED] 1) user address field
[SOLVED] 2) Verification if the checkbox of the Terms and Conditions is checked before validating
[SOLVED] 3) A simple message saying to user that he is successfuly registered

[SOLVED] I really don't know how to start to achieve this...

[SOLVED] Somebody here can help me to do this?

Thanks & Regards

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Bulletin de participation</title>
 <!-- Mobile Specific Metas -->
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
 <!-- Font-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/opensans-font.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/line-awesome/css/line-awesome.min.css">
 <!-- Jquery -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">
 <!-- Main Style Css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body class="form-v4">
 <div class="page-content">
       <form class="form-detail" action="reg.php" method="post" id="myform">
        <h2>Bulletin de participation</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="form-row form-row-1">
          <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input-text">
         </div>
         <div class="form-row form-row-1">
          <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="input-text">
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
         <label for="address">Address</label>
         <input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="input-text"">
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
         <label for="your_email">Email</label>
         <input type="text" name="your_email" id="your_email" class="input-text" required pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="form-row form-row-1 ">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input-text" required>
         </div>
         <div class="form-row form-row-1">
          <label for="comfirm-password">Repeat password</label>
          <input type="password" name="comfirm_password" id="comfirm_password" class="input-text" required>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-checkbox">
         <label class="container"><p>    <a href="terms.html" target="_blank"  class="text">I agree</a></p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked>
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
         </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row-last">
         <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Validate Form">
        </div>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
     <script>
     
      jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        debug: true,
         success:  function(label){
              label.attr('id', 'valid');
           },
      });
      
      $("#myform").validate().element("#checkbox");
      $( "#myform" ).validate({
      

         rules: 
       {
           password: "required",
           comfirm_password: {
              equalTo: "#password"
           }
        
         },

       
         messages: {
          first_name: {
           required: "Please enter a firstname"
          },
          last_name: {
           required: "Please enter a lastname"
          },
          your_email: {
           required: "Please provide an email"
          },
          password: {
           required: "Please enter a password"
          },
          comfirm_password: {
           required: "Please enter a password",
              equalTo: "Wrong Password"
           }
         }
      });
     </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I managed to make the form half working and to be recorded by a PHP script named reg.php
But now I'm looking to validate if all field are filled before accepting the validation.

Any idea?

Comment: What have you tried already? "Don't know how to start" is pretty vague, so you should probably check any tutorial first?

Comment: @NicoHaase Hi thanks fr your reply, I'm trying to, I readed a bunch of tutorial but they are all different and I don't understand how to implement them in the form.

Edit: I managed to do some nice thing but I am unable for the moment to make the form validate all the field before submit...